# Iron form not submitting on enter with paper input

Tags: polymer, web-component, iron-form

I'm testing out using `iron-form` with custom elements. The issue I'm having is the form is not being submitted when I press enter. For example this form right here works on enter:

```
    <iron-form>
      <form id="loginForm">
        <paper-card heading="Welcome Back!" elevation="1" animated-shadow="true">
            <div class="card-content">
              <input type="text" label="Username" value="{{username}}">
              <input type="text" label="Password" value="{{password}}">
            </div>
            <div class="card-actions">
                <button disabled$="[[fetching]]" type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </paper-card>
      </form>
    </iron-form>
```

I have an event listener in my connectedCallback method listening for the `iron-form-presubmit event`

```
        connectedCallback() {
          super.connectedCallback();

          this.addEventListener('iron-form-presubmit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('working')
          });
        }
```

The issue is when I switch the html input elements to paper-input elements the form no longer submits on enter.

```
    <iron-form>
      <form id="loginForm">
        <paper-card heading="Welcome Back!" elevation="1" animated-shadow="true">
            <div class="card-content">
              <paper-input type="text" label="Username" value="{{username}}"></paper-input>
              <paper-input type="text" label="Password" value="{{password}}"></paper-input>
            </div>
            <div class="card-actions">
                <button disabled$="[[fetching]]" type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </paper-card>
      </form>
    </iron-form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`<iron-a11y-keys>`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-a11y-keys) to call a submit method when the `[enter]` key is pressed.

```
<iron-a11y-keys target="loginForm" keys="enter" on-keys-pressed="submit"></iron-a11y-keys>
<iron-form id="loginForm">
...
</iron-form>
```

In your custom element definition, add a method:

```
submit: function () {
    this.$.loginForm.submit();
}
```

Comment: Is this the recommended approach or is there some sort of bug in iron form?

Comment: I don't know sorry. If it's a bug it's rather in paper-input that doesn't transmit the [enter] event to it's container.

Comment: idk if it's a "bug" or just a "limitation". Probably the latter (https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-form/issues/189)